# Stock price History Database Design

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I need to store the stock price history. Below are the requirements,

1. First 30 days hourly data should available
2. For 10 years history has to be maintained, which should contain daily high & low

There are multiple view types,

- Day wise - show hourly data if available, otherwise show high & low
- Week wise - show 7 days high & low
- Monthly wise - show 30 days high & low
- Yearly wise - Show 12 months high & low (each month's high & low,
  so 12 entries)

The table design is

```
HourlyStockPrice

symbol
datetime
price

DayStockPrice

symbol
date
high
low

MonthStockPrice

symbol
date
high
low
```

Since the database will have millions of record, I decided to store information in separate tables, so retrieval will be faster. Is this fine? or I need to go with only single table and based on need, the data has to be queried and processed. Below is single table schema,

```
StockPrice

symbol
datetime
high
low
```

Please advise.

Comment: *"I decided to store information in separate tables"* Why? Are you not aware of partitioning? For archival, you can certainly have separate tables, but not for production. How many symbols are you storing? If you're storing Hourly, why can't you just get the high and low from that data?

Comment: He is not aware of partitioning. He also thinks "millions of records" are a lot of information. And he stores - seemingly - the symbol in every line as a string.

Comment: Seems more like a Datawarehouse design, then a database design.  Frequently DW's are denormalized and flattened.

Comment: This is a data warehouse.  There's nothing operational about historical stock data.  Keep the three tables for maximum select performance.  Good luck figuring out how to add rows to the daily and the monthly stock price tables.  You should also have a table of stock symbols, the company name, and other company information.  A company's stock symbol can change over time.

Comment: There will be one webservice which inserts the current stock price. A worker thread will retrieve the data and update all these tables (daily, monthly). I want the maximum select performance.

Comment: Sorry. I am not aware of partitioning. I agree it is data warehousing,  there wont be any operation on inserted data. It is for read-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't mentioned how these tables get populates. My solution would be to have a trigger on the main stock price table that populates a single history table with the datetime of insert and updates with before and after prices.

You should be able to do all the rest with indexed views on the history table breaking down the updated (datetime) field into hours, days, months.

In case you're not familiar with indexed views they are simply views that you can index. The index data is kept with the view instead of the table.

The Hour Example may be something like...

```
CREATE VIEW ivHourlyStockPrice
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
     SELECT symbol, convert(varchar(255),updated,106) as Day, select convert(char(2), updated,108) as Hour, AfterPrice as CurrentPrice
     FROM StockHistory
END

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_ivHourlyStockPrice ON ivHourlyStockPrice(symbol,Day,Hour,CurrentPrice)
```

Then doing something like...

```
select Day, Hour, CurrentPrice
from ivHourlyStockPrice
where Day='03 Jun 2014'
  and symbol='xxx'
```

would be extremely fast.

Comment: As per MSDN "Indexed views work best when the underlying data is infrequently updated. The maintenance of an indexed view can be greater than the cost of maintaining a table index. If the underlying data is updated frequently, the cost of maintaining the indexed view data may outweigh the performance benefits of using the indexed view. If the underlying data is updated periodically in batches but treated primarily as read-only between updates, consider dropping any indexed views before updating, and rebuilding them afterward. Doing this may improve performance of the updates"

Comment: No more costly than the tables you're suggesting. It's just extra data that is index data rather than table data, but the database would create it rather than you. There maybe other reasons that prevent this solution buts it's definitely worth a proper investigation.

Comment: One other thing you might consider, but maybe not possible, is populating the history table every hour, or over night via a job. That would take any extra overhead out of the equation.